# AddActionListener not working on my JButton

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener

I'm trying to put an action listener on a `JButton` called btnNew which is in my view:

### View:

```
public class MyWindow6 extends JFrame
{
    private JButton btnNew;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6579944958990616196L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
        MyWindow6 myWindow = new MyWindow6();
        myWindow.setVisible( true );

        public MyWindow6()
        {
            super( "JMenu sample" );

            btnNew = new JButton( new ImageIcon( "icons/save.png"));
            this.setSize(1200,800);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

            JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();

            JScrollPane leftScrollPane = new JScrollPane( new JTree());
            leftScrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 0));
            contentPane.add( leftScrollPane, BorderLayout.WEST);

            JTable t = new JTable(DaoClef.createModel());
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(t);
            t.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

            add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            // toolbar
            JToolBar jtb = new JToolBar();
            btnNew.setToolTipText("Ajouter clef (CTRL + N");
            jtb.add(btnNew);
            contentPane.add(jtb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
        
        public JButton getBtnNew() {
            return btnNew;
        }
        public void setBtnNew(JButton btnNew) {
            this.btnNew = btnNew;
        }
    }
}
```

controller :

```
public class Controller2 {

    private DaoClef dao;
    private MyWindow6 view;

    public Controller2(DaoClef d, MyWindow6 v) {
        dao = d;
        view = v;
    }

    public void initController() {

        view.getBtnNew().addActionListener(e -> delete());
    }

    private void delete() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I got no error, just the `println` not working at all.

Do you got an idea why this is not working?
It seems the controller and view are not connected.

And if you got any advice about using MVC with Swing, I'm a little confused because I don't know where to put my listener.

Comment: *"AddActionListener not working on my JButton"* Which button? In cases like this, there should only be one. Get it working with one, and the answer for two or more will likely be obvious. More generally: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: hello , i'm trying on one : btnNew

Comment: Post an MCVE / SSCCE.

Comment: Is it better ? sorry i'm new

Comment: The posted code is not mcve. It does not even compile, has code that is not relevant to the question (like `Dao`) and `Controller2` which is not used at all. Please read the link provided carefully.

Comment: When you have code you think is an MCVE / SSCCE, test it fulfills all parts of the requirements. Specifically, for a run-time problem, that it compiles cleanly and runs. Now try copy/pasting that code above into a new project in your IDE, and tell me: Does it compile?

Comment: It does not compile because you have constructor (`public MyWindow6()`) and other methods (like `getBtnNew`) inside the `main` method. That is incorrect syntax. And btnNew is not a static field. So, it is not available in the static `main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting mcve like the following one, makes problem ans solution easy to understand and reproduce:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyWindow6 extends JFrame
{
    private final JButton btnNew;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Controller2(new MyWindow6());
    }
    public MyWindow6()      {

        btnNew = new JButton( "Delete");
        this.setSize(120,80);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        add(btnNew, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public JButton getBtnNew() {
        return btnNew;
    }
}

class Controller2 {

    private final MyWindow6 view;

    public Controller2(MyWindow6 v) {

        view = v;
        view.getBtnNew().addActionListener(e -> delete());
    }

    private void delete() {
        System.out.println("delete btn clicked");
    }
}
```